# Microsoft Azure Emulator shows - java.exe has not started - waiting

Tags: eclipse, jsp, azure, cloud

I am new to Microsoft Azure cloud. I am trying to test my Dynamic we project in Emulator. It has a message saying that

```
[WaWorkerHost.exe] java.exe has not started - waiting...
```

Kindly Assist to resolve this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did u get what was causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: I am not able to resolve it. I have gone to AWS

Comment: thanks for reply. I was able to figure out the problem (at least in my case) , I was giving wrong path for my jboss server while creating azure deployment package.